# xsd schema not presented by wsdl

Tags: xsd, wsdl, jax-ws

I'm developing WebService with JAX-WS(i'm using wsimport goal on jaxws-maven-plugin). I wrote a WSDL that imports a XSD schema.

```
WEB-INF/wsdl/service.wsdl
WEB-INF/wsdl/service.xsd
```

Also I generated web service classes and created endpoint and all. Everything worked great so far. When I ran my service on Tomcat 7 everything is ok. I can access a wsdl in my browser from:

```
http://localhost:8080/webService/servlet-url?wsdl
```

but I cannot get access to a xsd schema. The problem is in this wsdl:

```
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://ws.service/domain/1.0" schemaLocation="service.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

Of course during generation of classes wsdl and xsd are on local path but i want them to be remotely accessible when web service is running. I know that schemaLocation should be something like this "http://localhost:8080/webService/servlet-url?xsd=1".

In wsdl presented in browser import schould look like:

```
<xsd:schema>
    <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.service/domain/1.0" schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/webService/servlet-url?wsdl&resource=service.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
```

localhost:8080/webService/servlet?wsdl gives me:

```
wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://ws.serv.com/Service/1.0" name="emuiaService">         
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://ws.serv.com/Service/domain/1.0" schemaLocation="schema.xsd"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="halloMsg">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="dom:halloRequest"/>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="halloResponseMsg">
    <wsdl:part name="return" element="dom:halloResponse"/>
</wsdl:message>
```

and so on...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I almost can't believe that this was such a difficult problem to solve!

I've been googling like mad to find a solution to exactly this problem! Then I've been struggling really hard to find a solution on my own. By debugger-stepping through the java-6-openjdk's default javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider implementation (the "factory" in the JRE that creates the javax.xml.ws.Endpoint objects that you use for publishing web services) I finally learnt some things, which helped me to craft a solution that at least works in Java SE, at least in my current JRE, which is:

```
java version "1.6.0_33"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.5) (6b33-1.13.5-1ubuntu0.12.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

Whether this solution is usable in Java EE I don't know yet.

Here is how I solved it:

```
package myservice;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class App 
{
    private static final String MY_SERVICE_XSD = "/wsdl/MyService.xsd";

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        Endpoint ep = Endpoint.create(new MyEndpointImpl());

        ep.setMetadata(Arrays.asList(sourceFromResource(MY_SERVICE_XSD)));

        ep.publish("http://localhost:8080/svc/hello");
    }

    private static Source sourceFromResource(String name) {
        URL resource = App.class.getResource(name);
        String systemId = resource.toExternalForm();
        InputStream inputStream;
        try {
            inputStream = resource.openStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create InputStream from resource \""+ name +"\"", e);
        }
        return new StreamSource(inputStream, systemId);
    }
}
```

The crucial thing is that I first use method Endpoint#create (not Endpoint#publish) to get an *unpublished* Endpoint. Then I add the XSD-file as "meta data" to the (still unpublished) Endpoint (code "ep.setMetaData(...)"). *Then* I publish the endpoint (code "ep.publish(...)").

Now when I access `http://localhost:8080/svc/hello?wsdl` I get:

```
    <definitions targetNamespace="http://somewhere.net/my/namespace" name="MyService">
        <types>
            <xsd:schema>
                <xsd:import namespace="http://somewhere.net/my/namespace"
                            schemaLocation="http://localhost:8080/svc/hello?xsd=1"/>
            </xsd:schema>
        </types>
                  ...
    </definitions>
```

and my XSD-file is available from `http://localhost:8080/svc/hello?xsd=1`!

Note that my MyService.wsdl file on disk still contains:

```
            <xsd:schema>
                <xsd:import namespace="http://somewhere.net/my/namespace"
                            schemaLocation="MyService.xsd"></xsd:import>
            </xsd:schema>
```

Comment: I really don't remember what I did... probably switched to contract last but thanks for resolving it. I hope it helps someone someday ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here we go.

Into WSDL file to modificate something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<wsdl:definitions
      targetNamespace="http://service.wsr.company.com/" 
      name="webServiceExample" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
      xmlns:tns="http://servicio.wsr.baz.com/" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
```

On this little snippet important are xmlns tag. Those serve for deployment of schema XSD. Next

```
<wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema 
        xmlns:tns="http://service.wsr.company.com/" 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        targetNamespace="http://service.wsr.company.com/" version="1.0">

        ...

    </xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

Into those tag below you'll get what you have in `service.xsd` file or show it in `http://localhost:8080/webService/servlet-url?xsd=1` we continue

```
    <wsdl:message name="your_method_name">
         <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:your_method_name"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="your_method_nameResponse">
         <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:your_method_nameResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
```

Those above tag are show your method name. Next

```
    <wsdl:portType name="webServiceExample">
          <wsdl:operation name="your_method_name">
            <wsdl:input message="tns:your_method_name"/>
              <wsdl:output message="tns:your_method_nameResponse"/>
          </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
```

Those above tar are for put your operation's. Continue

```
    <wsdl:binding name="webServiceExamplePortBinding" type="tns:webServiceExample">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <wsdl:operation name="your_method_name">
          <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <wsdl:input>
              <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
              <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
```

Next one :)

```
   <wsdl:service name="webServiceExample">
     <wsdl:port name="webServiceExamplePort" binding="tns:webServiceExamplePortBinding">
       <soap:address location="REPLACE_WITH_ACTUAL_URL"/>
</wsdl:port>
```

And finally finished :)

**Note that you have to change the current tag by tag** `<wsdl:...></wsdl:...>`

You save it, the public and you have fun **XSD schema is presented in the WSDL**.

I hope help you. Ciao.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Still schema xsd isn't presented via http.

Comment: Please, show me how do you doing and show me your WSDL file. :)